# upload picture fail to system

Tags: c#, web-services

I created a form to upload picture to my system but picture uploading fails.

I tried whether my web service was connected using `getCurrentTime()` in my system and it is successfully connected.

My friend told me that it should be a server problem but my friend and I really have no idea on how to check whether our server was successfully connected to our system.

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Thank in advance.

my code

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        if (File2.PostedFile != null)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File2.PostedFile.FileName);
        }
        if (fileName != string.Empty)
        {
            if (!this.CheckFileFormat(fileName))
            {
                WindowJS.WindowAlert("Image format is incorrect !");
                return;
            }
            string server = ImageURL;
            string unique = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string filePath = server.TrimEnd('\\').TrimEnd('/') + ImageURLRelative + unique + "." + fileName.Split('.')[1].ToString();
           // string LocalfilePath = Server.MapPath("..") + unique + "." + fileName.Split('.')[1].ToString();
            string uploadFileName = unique + "." + fileName.Split('.')[1].ToString();
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile mFile = File2.PostedFile;

                int fileSize = mFile.ContentLength;
                int done = 0;

                byte[] mFileByte = new Byte[fileSize];
                mFile.InputStream.Read(mFileByte, 0, fileSize);

                string WebServiceUrl = string.Empty;


                try
                {                    
                    Rewards.high5.RedemptionUpload high5UploadService = new Rewards.high5.RedemptionUpload();

                    if (Brand == "high5")
                    {
                        done = high5UploadService.UploadImage(uploadFileName, mFileByte);

                        if (done == 1)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WindowJS.WindowAlert("Error: Upload image fail.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    //else if (Brand == "TLC")
                    //{
                    //    done = TLCUploadService.UploadImage(uploadFileName, mFileByte);
                    //}


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WindowJS.WindowAlert("Error: Upload image fail.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { WindowJS.WindowAlert(ex.Message.ToString()); }
            try
            {
                File2.PostedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                ImgUrl.ImageUrl = ImageURLRelative + unique + "." + fileName.Split('.')[1].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WindowJS.WindowAlert(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            ViewState["IMG"] = ImageURLRelative + unique + "." + fileName.Split('.')[1].ToString();
        }
        if (txtName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            WindowJS.WindowAlert("Please input the Name !");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            Convert.ToDecimal(txtPoint.Text.Trim());
        }
        catch
        {
            WindowJS.WindowAlert("Please input the Points correctly");
            return;
        }
        if (ViewState["Type"].ToString() == "E")
        {
            int rows = EditRedemption();
            if (rows == 0)
            {
                WindowJS.WindowAlert("Failed to modify");
            }
            else
            {
                WindowJS.WindowAlert("Modified successfully");
                LoadInfo("V");

            }


            return;
        }
        else if (ViewState["Type"].ToString() == "A")
        {
            AB5VIP.BLL.Redemption red = new AB5VIP.BLL.Redemption();
            if (red.Exists_RedName(txtName.Text.Trim()))
            {
                WindowJS.WindowAlert("This Redemption already existed !");
                return;
            }
            int rows = AddRedemption();
            WindowJS.WindowAlert(rows == 0 ? "Failed to save" : "save successfully");
        }
        else if (ViewState["Type"].ToString() == "V")
        {
            AB5VIP.BLL.Redemption redlang = new AB5VIP.BLL.Redemption();

            int rows = redlang.UpdateRedemptionLang(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ID"].ToString()), ddlLang.SelectedItem.Value, txtName.Text, txtTitle.Text.ToString(), txtDesc.Text, Session["ABP_LoginName"].ToString(), System.DateTime.Now);
            WindowJS.WindowAlert(rows == 0 ? "Failed to save" : "save successfully");
        }
        lblCode.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: thx ravi for help me edit my code~i was new at here~blur with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application need writing permission on the folder where you're going to save the pictures. Depending wich version of IIS you're running, permissions most be granted to ASPNET user (IIS 6) or the account used for application pool (IIS 7).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/08/20/why-can-i-upload-a-file-without-iis-write-permission.aspx

Best regards.

Comment: hi Oscar, how to get the permission? and the step is?

thx for reply

Comment: As I say, depends of the IIS version your running. Which one you have?

Comment: if i not mistake~my IIS version is IIS 7